# Optimise a MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL 8.0.20 and I have a huge table with some data in it.

```
CREATE TABLE `db_table` (
    `utcDateTime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
    `dateTime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
    `col1` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `col2` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `col3` varchar(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',  
    `col4` varchar(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1', 
    `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),  
    UNIQUE KEY `idx_dateIns` (`utcDateTime`,`col2`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8'
```

Below is the query I am trying to optimise,

```
SELECT col3,col4 
from db_table 
WHERE col2='123456' 
  AND (dateTime BETWEEN '2020-11-25 00:01' AND '2020-11-26 00:00') 
group by utcDateTime 
order by utcDateTime asc limit 1;
```

This query takes about 12 seconds to execute. But if I change the sorting order to desc, it takes about 0.015 seconds.

Can someone please help optimise the query or the database table?

Thank you

Comment: Please provide at least sample data and the execution plan

Comment: The query is not correct or you have `only_full_group_by disabled` [db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5a00e6d720107a003c01a968e71c1e9a)

Comment: A composite index on (col2, dateTime, utcDateTime) should help you there.

Comment: After removing the `group by utcDateTime`, the query still takes the same time as before 11 seconds. I am trying to understand why changing the ordering affects the query this much.

Comment: Is here any correlation between `utcDateTime` & `dateTime` fields?

Comment: No there is no correlation between utcDateTime & dateTime fields, only UNIQUE KEY `idx_dateIns` (`utcDateTime`,`col2`)

Comment: The query is nonsensical, so its optimisation is meaningless. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I have given this some thought. First, it turns out that the query is valid. By limiting the rows to one `col2` and then grouping by `utcDateTime`, all selected columns are functionally dependent from the group. It makes no sense to group by `utcDateTime`, because in combination with `col2` it is unique anyway, but it doesn't render the query invalid. As to the huge difference between `ASC` and `DESC`: this really surprises me, too. It seems the DBMS uses the unique index in one case and not in the other, but still ... Maybe `EXPLAIN` could tell us more.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Thanks for your valuable comment. That's absolutely correct, `(utcDateTime,col2)` have unique index so there's no need to group by `utcDateTime` which I have now removed but still doesn't make any difference on the execution time. I will try EXPLAIN now